# Stop Audio Player after X minutes

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I'm working on an Audio App. One task that I must accomplish is to be able to stop the audio player after X minutes (defined by user), like a player sleep.

To do it, I use local notifications.

This is the code in my custom player:

```
- (void)configureSleepTimer:(NSUInteger)seconds {
    UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:seconds];
    localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;

    NSDictionary *userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:@[@"PlayerSleep"] forKeys:@[@"type"]];
    localNotification.userInfo = userInfo;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
    NSLog(@"Notification: %@", localNotification);
}
```

AppDelegate:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {
    if ([[notification.userInfo valueForKey:@"type"] isEqualToString:@"PlayerSleep"]) {
        Player *player = [Player sharedInstance];
        [player stopPlayer];
    }
}
```

The problem with the above code, is that the player does not stops when the app is running in the background.

To get this run in the background, I check when the app enters in background mode and check if exists local notifications. If exists, I fire a one second timer to compare notifications firetimes with real date to stop the player if needed.

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        if ([[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications] count]) {
            NSTimer *t = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(sleepPlayer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
            [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:t forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
            [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];
        }
    });
}

- (void)sleepPlayer {
    [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UILocalNotification *notification, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
        NSString *dateTimeStr = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
        NSString *notifDateStr = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:-1 sinceDate:notification.fireDate]];

        if ([dateTimeStr isEqualToString:notifDateStr]) {
            Player *player = [Player sharedInstance];
            [player stopPlayer];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:notification];

            NSLog(@"************************** Player Sleeped");
        }
    }];
}
```

It works, but, I don't like this last piece of code. Is there a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution1.** I have implemented something similar, but not the exact thing what you want. What I did was, when track finishes, check the sleep time, and if it's exceeded, stop the player, which was passive way of implementing sleep timer with player. Maybe, this solution will work for you too?

**Solution2.** If your app supports background modes, i.e. it plays audio on the background, you can schedule timer (no need to begin background task) to be called on exact time with `initWithFireDate:` initialization method of `NSTimer`. Doing so, you timer won't be called every second, but on exact time.

Hope this was helpful. Good luck!

P.S.: keep in mind, both solutions require your app to be registered for background modes, at least audio.

Comment: Solution 1 won't be useful for me. The audio can or can't finish. Can be a track or a radio streaming. From now, I will try a mix of your solution 2 and my current implementation. BTW, of course needed background modes are enabled.